# What is an efficient way to copy Web Part pages from a dev server to a production server?

Tags: development, deployment, web-part-pages

I have 29 web part pages, all very similar in structure. I built them using the browser. I'd like to migrate them from a development server to a production server. I tried copying them using both Sharepoint Designer and the `Export-SPWeb` cmdlet, but had no luck with either. Right now I am looking at rebuilding all of the pages from scratch. Is there any efficent way to get these files copied over?

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean "no luck" with SharePoint Designer? At worst you should be able to cut and paste the pages with SharePoint Designer? You could try a content publishing job, or try saving the library containing the pages as a list template with content, and then copy the list across farms.

Comment: I guess the web part information is not stored in the aspx page, because the pages I came out with were blank web part pages when using both SPD and Powershell.

Comment: Ah, me thinking like a dev instead of an Admin. Web Part configuration is stored in the ASPX page, Web Part content is stored (for Web Parts like the Content Editor) in the content database. Cutting and pasting the code behind will move the page (without content). To move a Web Part page that has user-entered content you have to save the list as a template with content, move the list template, then recreate the list from the template on the remote site.

Comment: You could always consider doing a full site collection backup and restore, then using the move function within SharePoint to move between sites within a farm too, then deleting the temporary site collection.

Comment: Yes, I agree, it should not be this hard...

Comment: I'm not even sure that configuration is stored in the ASPX page, my experiences have led me to assume that configuration is also stored in content databases. It looks to me like the only thing that is stored in the ASPX page of a Web Part page is the layout of the web parts relative to each other on the page, unless there is some other thing involved that I haven't uncovered yet. It looks like I'll have to rebuild each page. Thanks!